# Verificacion propiedad dominio .com.ar - Argentina

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dominio

Hola tengo en mi propiedad un dominio .com.ar de Argentina. Intento agregar este dominio al Hosting de Firebase y me pide verificar la propiedad del dominio agregando unos registros TXT en mi proveedor DNS.
En nic.ar me dicen que eso lo tengo que hacer en mi servicio de Hosting pero mi servicio de Hosting me dice que lo tengo que hacer en mi proveedor DNS
Estoy perdido, no logro entenderlo. En Afip tambien intente agregarlos pero no existe esa opcion.
Alguien que le haya sucedido lo mismo?
Alguien que haya trabajado con Firebase y algun dominio .com.ar?
Gracias

Comment: Es en la configuración del DNS, añades el registro adicional

Comment: No conozco tu caso particular, pero en generar tu tienes 3 cosas distintas: 1) Dominio, 2) Hosting y 3) DNS. La mayoría de las veces el hosting ofrece servidor DNS, pero no siempre. Lo que debes buscar es un servicio que te ofrezca esto último o incluso si tienes algún conocido que tenga un hosting (con dns) el puede agregarlo a los suyos.

Comment: Perfecto gracias, voy a ver si me comunico con la empresa de hosting.